# Convert the Sender parameter of an event handler in order to read the control's Name?

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-6

I am writing a Form application using Borland C++Builder 6.0. I have put 2 `TImage` controls and I have generated the `OnClick` event handler as shown below:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Image1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
   AnsiString imageName;

   TImage *image;

   // How can I get the image name via the *Sender ?
   // How can I convert *Sender into TImage
   image = (TComponent)*Sender;

   imageName = image->Name;
}
```

I have assigned the same `OnClick` event on both of my `TImage` controls.

What I want to achieve is to have one event handler that reads the `Name` of the `TImage` which is clicked.

As far as I know, this can be done through the `TObject *Sender` parameter, but I cannot understand how I can convert the `Sender` into a `TImage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track that a simple type-cast will suffice, but your syntax is wrong.  Try this instead:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Image1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
   TImage *image = (TImage*)Sender;
   // alternatively:
   // TImage *image = static_cast<TImage*>(Sender);

   AnsiString imageName = image->Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorthand for simplification

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    ((TForm*) Sender)->Color = clRed;
}
```